# How to use Base64FileField together with the FileField?

Tags: django, django-rest-framework, django-serializer

I am using Django rest and initially, I used form-data to upload images to Django. My model has a FileField and it worked well. Right now, I need to handle **JSON** uploads also. I integrated this Base64FileField from the drf-extra-fields, added it to the serializer, but now my form-data request fails with the following error:

```
 "innitial_file_path": [
                "Invalid type. This is not an base64 string: <class 'django.core.files.uploadedfile.InMemoryUploadedFile'>"
            ]
```

How can I make it work for both the form-data and JSON request body? I suppose I still need to keep FileField in my model, but somehow convert base64 to the JSON. Also, should I create multiple serializers? Right now I have multiple nested serializes, so it would be difficult to use by creating multiple.

I would then need to get the **content-type** in the create method of the serializer and depending on that use different serializer. How can I get that?

My model:

```
class FileModel(AbstractModelBase):
    owner = models.ForeignKey(to=User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    title = models.CharField(max_length=32)
    innitial_file_path = models.FileField(validators=[FileExtensionValidator(allowed_extensions=['pdf'])],
                                          upload_to=file_directory_path)
    signed_file_path = models.FileField(validators=[FileExtensionValidator(allowed_extensions=['pdf'])],
                                        upload_to=file_directory_path, null=True, blank=True)
```

My serializer, which provides an error:

```
class FileModelSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    innitial_file_path = Base64FileField()
    class Meta:
        model = FileModel
        fields = ["title", "innitial_file_path"]
```

Comment: please add your model and serializers code snippets.

Comment: Are you posting using the rest-api html form? The api should only accept text data for the Base64FileField. Files uploaded using multipart/form-data would not be valid, right? drf-extra-fields has something called `HybridImageField` which looks like it accepts both multipart file uploads and b64-json.

Comment: @HåkenLid HybridImageField would suit, but I need a file field, not an image field. I upload pdfs. I paste with postman form-data, also from our mobile client.

If I could somehow get the content-type in the serializer, I could use different serializers, and could accept base64 and then convert it back to the file and store the file in the s3 storage.

Comment: The implementation is very straightforward. You could try writing a HybridFileField subclassing Base64FileField.  
https://github.com/Hipo/drf-extra-fields/blob/252e681765645322113f69131e786664f815b919/drf_extra_fields/fields.py#L157